# Excel autofit row height doesn't work on meged cells with word wrap

Tags: excel, vba

I'm programmatically inserting some text into merged cells in a row. I have Wrap Text set and want the row height to expand as necessary to accommodate multiple lines of text. I was programmatically applying AutoFit once the cells had been filled but that didn't work. I subsequently found a Knowledge Base article saying the AutoFit doesn't work for merged cells! I can try to compute the row height required to accommodate the number of lines of wrapping text. But I don't really want to climb into calculating character widths etc. Any ideas gratefully appreciated.

Question credit goes to David (I had the exact same question, just reposting here for posterity) [source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/76182-autofit-row-height-display-wrapped-text.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a VB macro [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/76182-autofit-row-height-display-wrapped-text.html) that will simulate the autofit of any merged cells on the active sheet. Source credits parry from MrExcel.com

```vb
Sub AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight()
Dim CurrentRowHeight As Single, MergedCellRgWidth As Single
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim ActiveCellWidth As Single, PossNewRowHeight As Single
Dim StartCell As Range, c As Range, MergeRng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim a() As String, isect As Range, i


'Take a note of current active cell
Set StartCell = ActiveCell

'Create an array of merged cell addresses that have wrapped text
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If c.MergeCells Then
    With c.MergeArea
    If .Rows.Count = 1 And .WrapText = True Then
        If MergeRng Is Nothing Then
            Set MergeRng = c.MergeArea
            ReDim a(0)
            a(0) = c.MergeArea.Address
        Else
        Set isect = Intersect(c, MergeRng)
            If isect Is Nothing Then
                Set MergeRng = Union(MergeRng, c.MergeArea)
                ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
                a(UBound(a)) = c.MergeArea.Address
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End With
End If
Next c


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop thru merged cells
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
Range(a(i)).Select
      With ActiveCell.MergeArea
            If .Rows.Count = 1 And .WrapText = True Then
                'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                CurrentRowHeight = .RowHeight
                ActiveCellWidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
                For Each CurrCell In Selection
                    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + MergedCellRgWidth
                Next
                .MergeCells = False
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergedCellRgWidth
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
                PossNewRowHeight = .RowHeight
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = ActiveCellWidth
                .MergeCells = True
                .RowHeight = IIf(CurrentRowHeight > PossNewRowHeight, _
                  CurrentRowHeight, PossNewRowHeight)
            End If
        End With
MergedCellRgWidth = 0
Next i

StartCell.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Clean up
Set CurrCell = Nothing
Set StartCell = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
Set MergeRng = Nothing
Set Cell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a heads-up for anyone planning to use this: This will not work if you have merged cells across multiple rows.